# Is there a Haskell combinator of type `(a -> a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> a -> a -> c`?

Tags: haskell, combinators

Does the following combinator have a name in Haskell? If not, can it be expressed in terms of simpler ones?

```hs
c f g x y = g (f x y) (f y x)
```

I have tried
Hoogle and pointfree.io (which gives me back an unintelligible expression)
but without success.

Comment: I assume the type is then `(a -> a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> a -> a -> c`?

Comment: Is it intentional that the arguments to `f` are flipped in the two calls to `f` shown?

Comment: If hoogle and pointfree.io don't have any suggestions, then I'd be shocked if one existed.  (Of course, you might have given them the wrong type, as pointed out by @willeM_VanOnsem.)

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: @chepner Yes this is intentional (you may think of the symmetric difference of two sets defined as the union of the differences)

Comment: If `f` took one argument, you would write `c = g <$> f <*> flip f`. To accommodate the two-argument function, you need to sprinkle in some (un)currying: `curry $ g <$> uncurry f <*> uncurry (flip f)`. I'm not aware of a pre-defined version of this.

Comment: @chepner This is not that bad, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is no known combinator for this as far as I know. We can however shorten this - with [the help of @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907492/is-there-a-haskell-combinator-of-type-a-a-b-b-b-c-a-a#comment137350157_77907492) - to:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)
import Control.Monad(ap)

ourCombinator :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
ourCombinator g = curry . ap (liftA2 g . uncurry) (uncurry . flip)
```

The `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c` converts a function with two parameters to one that takes one parameter: a 2-tuple with the two parameters.

We then use `liftA2 g` that will apply `g` on the result of `uncurry f` and `uncurry (flip f)`, and then we `curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c` to convert it back to a function that takes two parameters.